# class is also spelled klass. how about module?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, 'class' is sometimes spelled 'klass' to prevent keyword conflicts:

```
def method(klass)
  klass.blah_blah_blah
end
```

How about the 'module' keyword? How do you spell it?

Comment: This question got closed so I can't answer, but I had the same question. I eventually settled on "modyule" to add a bit of christmas flare

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Call it whatever you want**

`klass` is just used as a convention.

How does `mod` suit you?

Or `modjewel` **-.-**

Comment: You are absolutely right. I prefer `modjewel` but choose `mod`. Thank you.